# Digital Magazine Subscription Software/Services

Tags: web-services, ecommerce

I have a client that would like to sell a digital magazine on an annual subscription basis.

In the past I've used WooCommerce with their Subscriptions add-on but found it a bit clunky. A major issue was that there was no way to block new subscribers from seeing old magazine issues unless I created a separate product for each new issue. This ended up being a lot of maintenance and updating for my client and I'd like something more automated.

Does anyone have any experience with other options out there?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Easy Digital Downloads](https://easydigitaldownloads.com). I nearly used it for a client (their spec changed halfway through) but it looks like it could work for you. It's aimed at digital subscriptions